# How to customize the Search View in Toolbar with a TextInputLayout / Android

Tags: android, searchview, hint

How do I change the standard Search View edit Text layout to a [TextInputLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TextInputLayout.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog) so that the hint text persists when user enter search.

An example would be greatly appreciated.